# WebSharper - JQuery and HTTPS reference

Tags: jquery, websharper

After deploying w# client page to the github pages, I got the following error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://aph5nt.github.io/websharper.amplifyjs/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.(anonymous function) @ SampleApp.head.js:1
amplify.js:830 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

Is it possible somehow to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a quick look, the problem is that jQuery is referenced, incorrectly, in WebSharper core via `http`:

```ml
Namespace "WebSharper.JQuery.Resources" [
    Resource "JQuery" "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"
    |> fun r -> r.AssemblyWide()
]
```

(https://github.com/intellifactory/websharper/blob/5c884e97fd3dba1102c10a85b171f672d0b3f637/src/stdlib/WebSharper.JQuery/Definition.fs#L1120)

This causes every reference to jQuery to automatically pull in the above resource, and applications served over `https` will fail to load it.

Until this is fixed, you can override your reference to jQuery in your `web.config` to use a protocol-less URL:

```
<appsettings>
    <add key="WebSharper.JQuery.Resources.JQuery" value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" />
    ...
```

Hope this helps.